# Aggregating iCal calendars

Tags: calendar, ics

I have iCal (.ics) files from a few different sources (work, client, personal, social) and systems (Google, Outlook 365, Fastmail).

I'd like to aggregate them all into a single feed for my colleagues, friends, and family to consume.  Ideally, with fine-grained access and visibility controls.

All Google Apps support was able to suggest was to convert all my clients and friends to Google Calendar, and then it'd be easy

Does a tool (commercial / free / Free) exist to solve this problem?  I don't want to reinvent the wheel if I don't have to.  Googling has turned up nothing so far.

Comment: You could create a brand new 'unified' calendar feed and then import all your various ical feeds that way (and share the ical URL of your unified calendar with your colleagues et al). I use TeamUp sometimes - have a read of this and see if it works for you: https://medium.com/teamup/how-to-consolidate-multiple-calendar-feeds-into-a-single-view-145d598235fc